# Получить данные из бд, что бы проверить через if

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

nb Я написал код

```
var t = "0";
var c = db.Players.SqlQuery("SELECT IDtest FROM dbo.Players WHERE Id = {0} AND IDtest = 0", id);
if (c == t) {
```

и не работает, как правильно написать? мне нужно проверить, что значение по запросу равна нулю или единице

Comment: "и не работает" - а что делает?

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: дело в том, что я не могу перевести sql запрос в int

Comment: Ну да. Надо прочитать результат. Вот пример https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/5.1.php

Comment: Читал я эти материалы, но мне нужно вытаскивать данные из бд, и на основе этих данных проводить логическое сравнение. Но если просто так вывести, его нельзя преобразовать в другой тип данных

Comment: Вот этот запрос на sql SELECT IDtest FROM dbo.Players WHERE Id = {0} AND IDtest = 0, он мне выводит число 1

Comment: Укажите в вопросе БД(MySql, oracle, Ms sql...) c которой работаете, а так же DDL таблицы к которой вы делаете запрос. Данный запрос не может вам вернуть 1, или вы про то что не получаете равенство в if ?